# Cannot update "AnnotationHub"

Tags: r, updates

I'm trying to update my AnnotationHub package to a higher version. Now what I have is 2.18.0. But I tried directly install AnnotationHub by using:

```
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install("AnnotationHub",version = "3.10")
 
library("AnnotationHub")
```

But the version is still not changed. I also tried removing the old installation first then reinstall, still can't solve the issue. My R version is 3.6.3.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that is the highest version of AnnotationHub available for that version of R. Try updating R...the current version of R is 4.0.5

Edit - you'll also have to update BiocManager.